# React Bootstrap grid spanning full width within tab pane

Tags: react-bootstrap

I have a react component laying out a grid of other components within a tab pane, all from react-bootstrap and contained within a div that has bootstrap's nice centred, padded container going on. Unfortunately the Grid within the Tab seems to think it should extend all the way to the right-hand edge of the screen. How can I make sure it sticks within the parent div's width?

Here's the essence of the code:

```js
render() {
    return (
    <div class="container">
        <Tabs>
          <Tab>
            <Grid>
              <Row>
                <Col md={12}>
                  <Panel>
                    Hi
                  </Panel>
                </Col>
             </Row>
          </Grid>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    </div>           
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use Grid's fluid prop to turn the Grid from fixed-width layout into a full-width layout.
See: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#grid : Props

```js
render() {
    return (
    <div class="container">
        <Tabs>
          <Tab>
            <Grid fluid={true}>
              <Row>
                <Col md={12}>
                  <Panel>
                    Hi
                  </Panel>
                </Col>
             </Row>
          </Grid>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    </div>           
    );
  }
```